# Custom permalink not working and showing 404 page not error

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have created 1 custom post and some custom fields.

- Custom post type: Tour

  - Custom field: tour_id

Now I want to customize permalink link structure, want to append "tour_id" value in link. I'm using below code.

```
add_action('init', 'pub_rewrite_rules');

function pub_rewrite_rules() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%pstname%', '([^/]+)', 'post_type=tour&name=');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%tourid%', '([^/]{4})', 'tourid=');
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('tour', '/tour/%pstname%/%tourid%', array( 'walk_dirs' => false ));
}

function pub_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if((false !==strpos( $permalink, '%tourid%') ) && get_post_type($post)=='tour') {
     $publicationtype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_id',true);
     $rewritecode = array('%pstname%','%tourid%');
     $rewritereplace = array($post->post_name,$publicationtype);
     $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);    
  }
return $permalink;
}
```

I'm getting correct link "https://tourjourney/tour/tour-1/1000/" here, "tour" is custom post, "tour-1" is post title and "1000" is tour_id, but while viewing the post i'm getting "404 File Not Found error". [image: tour1] 
 I have done above code in function.php file of theme.
 I have checked .htaccess, it's proper.

I guess the problem is in add_permastruct or m'I missing anything in code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same technical need as you, and I have did this(code below) to get it work :

```
function my_custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%xxx%', '([^&]+)'); //change the regex to your needs
  add_rewrite_tag('%yyy%', '([^&]+)'); //change the regex to your needs
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);


function my_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^tour/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=tour&xxx=$matches[1]&yyy=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Finally, do not forget to flash the permalinks structure from your dashboard.

Comment: By 'flash the permalinks' do you mean press 'Save Changes' on Settings > Permalinks?

Comment: @Clinton, Yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I just modify {4} => + sign

my all posts is working proper.

{4} means it's taking only 4 digit of tourid

rest of code is same.

```
add_action('init', 'pub_rewrite_rules');

function pub_rewrite_rules() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%pstname%', '([^/]+)', 'post_type=tour&name=');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%tourid%', '([^/]+)', 'tourid=');
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('tour', '/tour/%pstname%/%tourid%', array( 'walk_dirs' => false ));
}
```